# Node.js 20x slower than browser (Safari) with Tesseract.Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, tesseract

New to JS and very new to Node. 
 Running Tesseract.js (text recognition software:  http://tesseract.projectnaptha.com) in Safari takes about 10 sec and begins outputting progress immediately.
  Node (v6.9.1)(run from terminal or through Electron) runs CPU to 100% for 4min 20sec before it begins outputting to console.  It then finishes in about the same time.

What troubleshooting steps are recommended?   Is this common for Node?
Only difference I see in logs is Safari "found in cache eng.traineddata" Clearing and disabling the cache only minimally affect the time. 
   Have tried a few .JPG and .PNG (300-600kb) files with same result - but BMP (3.7MB) gave fast 17 sec response - then errors and didn't finish.   (Is this a 'next tick' problem?)

```
var Tesseract = require('tesseract.js');  
var image = "./images/sample.jpg";

function tesseract(){
Tesseract.recognize(image)
.progress(function(message){console.log(message)})
.then(result => console.log(result.text))
} 
tesseract();
```

(the editor is forcing the output to be formatted as code)
NODE console.Log

```
>Bash-3.2$ node JustTess.js  
   *Waits 4+ min and Then*   
{ status: 'loading tesseract core' }  
{ status: 'loaded tesseract core' }  
{ status: 'initializing tesseract', progress: 0 }  
pre-main prep time:108 ms  
{ status: 'initializing tesseract', progress: 1 }  
{ status: 'loading eng.traineddata', progress: 0 }  
{ status: 'loading eng.traineddata', progress: 1 }  
{ status: 'initializing api', progress: 0 }   
{ status: 'initializing api', progress: 0.3 }   
{ status: 'initializing api', progress: 0.6 }   
{ status: 'initializing api', progress: 1 }   
{ status: 'recognizing text', progress: 0 }   
{ status: 'recognizing text', progress: 0.014285714 }...
```

SAFARI console.log

```
>[Log]  – {status: "loading tesseract core"}  
[Log]  – {status: "loaded tesseract core"}   
[Log]  – {status: "initializing tesseract api"}  
[Log] pre-main prep time: 115 ms (index.js, line 10)  
[Log]  – {status: "initialized tesseract api"}   
[Log]  – {status: "found in cache eng.traineddata"}   
[Log]  – {status: "loaded eng.traineddata"}   
[Log]  – {status: "initialized with language"}   
[Log]  – {status: "recognizing text", progress: 0}   
[Log]  – {status: "recognizing text", progress: 0.0142}...
```

NODE with BMP

```
bash-3.2$ node JustTess.js
*After 17 sec*
    { status: 'initializing tesseract', progress: 0 }
pre-main prep time: 118 ms
{ status: 'initializing tesseract', progress: 1 }
{ status: 'loading eng.traineddata', progress: 0 }
{ status: 'loading eng.traineddata', progress: 1 }
{ status: 'initializing api', progress: 0 }
{ status: 'initializing api', progress: 0.3 }
{ status: 'initializing api', progress: 0.6 }
Error in pixRemoveColormap: pixs must be {1,2,4,8} bpp
Error in pixGetDepth: pix not defined
Error in pixGetWpl: pix not defined
Error in pixCreateHeader: depth must be {1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 24, 32}
Error in pixCreateNoInit: pixd not made
Error in pixCreateTemplateNoInit: pixd not made
Error in pixCreateTemplate: pixd not made
Error in pixCopy: pixd not made
{ status: 'initializing api', progress: 1 }
3
3

/Users/brent/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Programming/GitHub/ba/node_modules/tesser
act.js-core/index.js:4
function f(a){throw a;}var h=void 0,i=!0,j=null,k=!1;function aa(){return function(){}}function ba(
a){return function(){return a}}var n,Module;Module||(Module=eval("(function() { try { return Tesser
actCore || {} } catch(e) { return {} } })()"));var ca={},da;for(da in Module)Module.hasOwnProperty(
da)&&(ca[da]=Module[da]);var ea=i,fa=!ea&&i;
              ^
abort(3) at Error
    at Error (native)
    at Na (/Users/brent/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Programming/GitHub/ba/node_mod
ules/tesseract.js-core/index.js:32:26)
    at ka (/Users/brent/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Programming/GitHub/ba/node_mod
ules/tesseract.js-core/index.js:507:108)
    at Array.JHa (/Users/brent/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Programming/GitHub/ba/n
ode_modules/tesseract.js-core/index.js:402:25808)
    at xd (/Users/brent/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Programming/GitHub/ba/node_mod
ules/tesseract.js-core/index.js:382:924)
    at R.TesseractCore.V.Begin (/Users/brent/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Programmi
ng/GitHub/ba/node_modules/tesseract.js-core/index.js:511:288)
    at DumpLiterallyEverything (/Users/brent/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Programmi
ng/GitHub/ba/node_modules/tesseract.js/src/common/dump.js:13:8)
    at /Users/brent/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Programming/GitHub/ba/node_modules
/tesseract.js/src/common/worker.js:121:22
    at /Users/brent/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Programming/GitHub/ba/node_modules
/tesseract.js/src/common/worker.js:92:9
    at /Users/brent/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Programming/GitHub/ba/node_modules
/tesseract.js/src/node/lang.js:14:25
If this abort() is unexpected, build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 which can give more information.
```

Comment: Tried their demo on my node(6.9.1) - works as fast in browser. Only thing that comes to mind - they require node 6.8 or higher, but you mentioned 6.7. Also this issue maybe the same that you have: https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js/issues/53

Comment: Thank you. Updated Node and tried with .png as well with same result.  And that does look like the same issue.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer the question; however, the other answers doesn't shed much light on the matter. See http://www.jsbenchmarks.com/?anywhichway/lookup/master/benchmark.js/ for an example of how NodeJS and browsers differ dramatically across a number of functions. Note, although the browser results on this site are from multiple visitors and the Node results are from a single server, tests in an isolated environment show the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been solved by an update to the Tesseract.Js software.