# Swift 3 - Tesseract recognize throwing errors for any image manipulation

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, avfoundation, tesseract

I am using Swift 3 and developing an application where the user takes a photo and uses Tesseract OCR to recognize the text in it.

The following code block works.

```
func processPhoto() {
    if let tesseract = G8Tesseract(language: "eng") {
        tesseract.delegate = self

        // this is the resulting picture gotten after running the capture delegate
        tesseract.image = stillPicture.image!
        tesseract.recognize()
    }
}
```

However, if I try to manipulate the picture at all (`stillPicture.image!`), I get the following error:

```
Error in pixCreateHeader: depth must be {1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 24, 32}
Error in pixCreateNoInit: pixd not made
Error in pixCreate: pixd not made
Error in pixGetData: pix not defined
Error in pixGetWpl: pix not defined
2017-03-13 11:13:05.336796 ProjectName[35238:9127211] Cannot convert image to Pix with bpp = 64
Error in pixSetYRes: pix not defined
Error in pixGetDimensions: pix not defined
Error in pixGetColormap: pix not defined
Error in pixClone: pixs not defined
Error in pixGetDepth: pix not defined
Error in pixGetWpl: pix not defined
Error in pixGetYRes: pix not defined
Please call SetImage before attempting recognition.Please call SetImage before attempting recognition.2017-03-13 11:13:05.343568 EOB-Reader[35238:9127211] No recognized text. Check that -[Tesseract setImage:] is passed an image bigger than 0x0.
```

Some things that I do to manipulate the picture is to rotate it:

```
// Rotate taken picture
let orig_image = stillPicture.image!

let new_image_canvas = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: stillPicture.image!.size.height,
                                                                  height: stillPicture.image!.size.width))
let new_image = new_image_canvas.image { _ in
    let curr_context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    curr_context.translateBy(x: 0, y: stillPicture.image!.size.width)
    curr_context.rotate(by: -.pi/2)
    stillPicture.image!.draw(at: .zero)
}

tesseract.image = new_image
```

If I do that, BOOM! The error above occurs.

Another manipulation I do is to crop portion of the image.

```
let finalImage : UIImage

let crop_section = CGRect(x: 590.0, y: 280.0, width: 950.0, height: 550.0)

let cg_image = stillPicture.image!.cgImage?.cropping(to: crop_section)
finalImage = UIImage(cgImage: cg_image!)      

tesseract.image = final_image
```

Again, BOOM! Error appears.  Any idea why this is happening and why my image manipulations are causing problems?  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever transformations you make to the image leave it in a format which Tesseract cannot understand. Tesseract uses the Leptonica library to handle image formats, and Leptonica can understand only images in a certain format.

The first line:

```
Error in pixCreateHeader: depth must be {1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 24, 32}
```

already is a big hint on what the error is. Bit depth means how many bits per pixel you have. For example a 24-bit image is usually RGB - you have 8-bits (or one byte) for red, green and blue each - total of 24-bits. 32-bits is for ARGB (RGB+alpha channel). 1 bit is monochrome.

See http://search.cpan.org/dist/Image-Leptonica/lib/Image/Leptonica/Func/pix1.pm#pixCreateHeader - pixCreateHeader is a leptopnica function.

So try the following - save the image to a file, and open it in some image editor and check what type of image it is, esp. the bit depth.

Apparently your image is using some weird bit depth. Also look at [Node.js 20x slower than browser (Safari) with Tesseract.Js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40463777/node-js-20x-slower-than-browser-safari-with-tesseract-js), because this is the only question that I could find where `Error in pixCreateHeader: depth must be {1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 24, 32}` is also mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Actually, I don't even know what fixed it but I took out the code that did my photo rotation and the photo is still being rotated (for some reason) and no more error.  :/

Comment: @noblerare  how you fixed it? I have this issue too.